# Array of arrays transformation into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

So I have a JSON array of arrays

```
[ [ "2015", "Honda", "CR-V", "1.5", "Turbo 7-Seater", "Automatic" ], [ "2016", "Mazda", "CX-5", "2.0", "Premium", "Manual" ] ]
```

And essentially, I need to create a new JSON object using the values in the JSON array plus keys such as below:

```
{
  "root": {
    "cars": [
      {
        "Year": "2015",
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Model": "CR-V",
        "Engine": "1.5",
        "Submodel": "Turbo 7-Seater",
        "Transmission": "Automatic"
      },
      {
        "Year": "2016",
        "Make": "Mazda",
        "Model": "CX-5",
        "Engine": "2.0",
        "Submodel": "Premium",
        "Transmission": "Manual"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm new to JSON and Javascript. Can anyone provide some tips and guidance? Thank you!

Comment: There is no such thing as "JSON array of arrays", it's just an array of arrays. Something is either valid JSON or not:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all these are Javascript `arrays` and `objects` and not `JsonArray` and `JSONObject`.

If the `object` properties are always the same, you can just `map` the array elements into respective objects:

```
var results = {
  "root": {
    "cars": arr.map(function(item) {
      return {
        "year": item[0],
        "make": item[1],
        "model": item[2],
        "engine": item[3],
        "submodel": item[4],
        "transmission": item[5]
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [
  ["2015", "Honda", "CR-V", "1.5", "Turbo 7-Seater", "Automatic"],
  ["2016", "Mazda", "CX-5", "2.0", "Premium", "Manual"]
];

var results = {
  "root": {
    "cars": arr.map(function(item) {
      return {
        "year": item[0],
        "make": item[1],
        "model": item[2],
        "engine": item[3],
        "submodel": item[4],
        "transmission": item[5]
      }
    })
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your original array to this function to get what you expected. As I know, you said that you're newbie in JS so my solution comes from simplest function (`forEach` of JS);

```
var rootObj = [ [ "2015", "Honda", "CR-V", "1.5", "Turbo 7-Seater", "Automatic" ], [ "2016", "Mazda", "CX-5", "2.0", "Premium", "Manual" ] ];


function convert(arr) {
  var result = { root: { cars: [ ] } };
  arr.forEach(function(val) {
    result.root.cars.push({
      "Year": val[0],
      "Maker": val[1],
      "Model": val[2],
      "Engine": val[3],
      "Submodel": val[4],
      "Transmission": val[5]
    })
  });
  return result;
}

// You can test the result with this line of code
var output = convert(rootObj);
console.log('RESULT: ', JSON.stringify(output));
```